# Do DevExpress controls require ASP.NET session?

Tags: asp.net, session, devexpress

Basically, if the session is turned off by using web.config will their controls still be **fully** functional?

Comment: Does the documentation state a dependency on the session?

Comment: Turn session off on your developer machine and test all the functionality you want. This is a question you should be asking DevExpress directly.

Comment: Not from what I have read.  For exporting they use BinaryStorageConfigurator.Mode that **can** use the session.

Comment: Oded - So you expect me to drop every dev express control on a web form and write code to test every property etc.?  I did ask dev express and I'm asking here for those that don't have devexpress yet and can't use their support site.

Comment: I expect that you test the functionality you are interested in instead of asking an open ended question (what do you mean by **fully**?) here.

Comment: Oded - It is obvious you don't know the answer to this question.  So why are you flaming?  If you're a developer then you know **exactly** what fully functional means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session is used by some of our controls, for example by XtraCharts, to store the image generated on the server.  However, all such controls are able to store the corresponding information, not only in the Session.  For the details, please refer to the [Binary Storage Configuration](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument6874) topic.  Also, the ASPxSpellChecker stores a custom dictionary in a Session.  This is implemented to provide a unique dictionary for every user.  Nothing else related to using Session in our ASP.NET controls comes to mind.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I did notice that even when setting BinaryStorageConfigurator.Mode to the default (Cache), I still received a standard session error when trying to export the chart.  I have already logged it as an issue about this and wanted to double check the response I received.  Currently, the answer I got from your support site is in conflict with this answer.

Comment: Hmmm, the exported image is actually stored in a Session :-(... Sorry, for misinforming you.  I will discuss this problem with the team after the weekend and update the ticket here and in the support center.

Comment: updated:  http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=B199134